# Obtener Fecha Actual en Español en Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Hola amigos saben algun metodo para obtener la fecha actual en Español, por ejemplo 12/02/2019 que sea 12 de Febrero del 2019 algo similar asi

Comment: Hola Alex, agrega el código que has tratado por favor o lo que has investigado, revisa [ask], recuerda que puedes realizar este tipo de consultas en el [chat], tienes suficiente reputación, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si hay manera, una usando DateTime y dandolo el formato que deseas en tu caso seria este formato...

```
Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda.